# Binomial theorem (solve this please)

Tags: binomial-theorem

If the two middle terms in the expansion of $( a+2b )^{2n+1}$ are equal then

(A) $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{2}$   (B) $a=4b$  (C) $a=8b$  (d) $a=2b$

Comment: Hint: by the binomial theorem the middle terms of the expansion are $\binom{2n+1}{n}a^n(2b)^{n+1}$ and $\binom{2n+1}{n+1}a^{n+1}(2b)^{n}$. Also what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to supistitute (n) with a numper that makes the value of n is odd

Comment: What did you find out from this?

Comment: If i supistitute n with 1 the answer will be a=2b                       And if i supistitute with 2 the answer will be a=4b                If i supistitute with 3 the answer will be a=8b

Comment: Please spellcheck your comments.

Comment: The only reason the this is done for an odd value is that it has two middle terms; The binomial theorem gives you all terms.  Just find what the binomial theorem tells you the two middle terms are and set them equal.  The middle terms are what Mosquite says they are.  If they are equal you can divide out common factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: with $n=0$, $(a+2b)^1=a+2b$, hence $a=2b$.

Comment: As the property is deemed to be true regarless $n$, there is no need to look further.

Answer (score 1):

Binomial theorem: $(K + L)^m = sum {m \choose i}*K^iL^{m-i}$.  Notice there are $m +1$ terms.

If there are $m= 2n + 1 $ there are $2n+2$ terms.  The first $n+1$ terms are $i = 0..... n$ and the second $n+1$ terms are $n+1,...... 2n+1$.  So the middle terms are $i =n$ and $i = n+1$.

So $(a+2b)^{2n+1} = sum {2n+1 \choose i}*a^{i}*(2b)^{2n+1 -i}$.

So for $i = n$ the term is ${2n+1 \choose n}*a^n*(2b)^{n+1}$.

For $i = n+1$ the term is ${2n+1 \choose n+1}*a^{n+1}*(2b)^n$

So we want ${2n+1 \choose n}*a^n*(2b)^{n+1} = {2n+1 \choose n+1}*a^{n+1}*(2b)^n$

One obvious thing to note:

${2n+1 \choose n} = \frac{(2n+1)!}{(2n+1-n)!n!} = \frac{(2n+1)!}{(n+1)!n!}=\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n+1)!(2n+1 - (n-1))!}= {2n+1 \choose n + 1}$

So, can you take it from there?